# How do you check for prop errors in a React/Typescript project with ESLint?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I am in the process of migrating a create-react-app Typescript project to the latest version of create-react-app, and with it I am moving from the now deprecated tslint to eslint. The issue I am having with this transition is that I cannot get eslint to throw either an error or a warning on missing props.

Take this sample React component:

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  count: number;
}

const ExampleComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const {name, count} = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {name} {count}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

that is then later called by another component:

```
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent';

const App = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <ExampleComponent count={5} />
  );
}
```

In the above example, the `count` prop is missing. This should result in an error or warning thrown by eslint, as it previously did with tslint. My IDE recognizes the missing prop and will highlight it, however I can still compile the code successfully, which it should not be doing.

How can I modify my eslint configuration in order to get an error whenever a prop is missing (or in the same sense, if an extra prop that shouldn't be there is there)?

Here is my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "project": "tsconfig.json",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc",
        "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow",
        "eslint-plugin-import",
        "eslint-plugin-react",
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "@typescript-eslint/tslint"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      ],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "off",
        "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
        "jsdoc/require-jsdoc": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
        "max-len": ["error", 200, 2, {
          "ignoreUrls": true,
          "ignoreComments": true,
          "ignoreRegExpLiterals": true,
          "ignoreStrings": true,
          "ignoreTemplateLiterals": true
        }],
        "no-prototype-builtins": "off"
    }
};
```

And below is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "strictFunctionTypes": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "build",
    "node_modules",
    "src/setupProxy.js",
    "archived"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You don't need ESLint to throw an error on that - TypeScript itself will fail to compile. Intellisense will also show you the issue in your IDE.

Comment: My IDE is performing correctly and highlighting the error. However TypeScript compiles with no errors, both in development and when I build production. My IDE alone isn't enough, as it only shows the error if I am currently looking at the file. I have edited the question and attached my tsconfig.json as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not a problem with ESLint not catching the error, but rather in the migration process to the newest version of create-react-app. Updating `react-scripts` (to version 4.0.1 at the time of writing this) does not also update the TypeScript version. The difference versions causes a number of errors not being properly reported. Updating Typescript to version 4.0.3 fixes the problem.

Comment: Could you expand on what exactly happened? I have been able to reproduce your issue on codesandbox, but starting a new CRA project does not compile, as expected.

Comment: I started a new CRA project to see if something was different as well, and had the same experience of it not compiling, as expected. After comparing both package.json files, my project was running TS 3.5.x, whereas the newest CRA project has 4.0.3. After upgrading my project to match, the errors began appearing again. Also of note is that I initially upgraded TS all the way to 4.1.x, but there are a number of jsx related errors that haven't been patched yet for that release, so I rolled back to 4.0.3

Comment: Perfect, the different between the minor versions is what I was experiencing too. Thank you for taking the time to explain!

Comment: It solved for me on react build for typescript later versions